# How to autofill subject line in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How to autofill subject line in Outlook for new messages, replies, and forwards?

I am now allowed to send [unsecure] emails from my agency, but have to manually put in [unsecure] for every email going out (replies, forwards, and new messages) in the subject line.

This is very time consuming.

Is there a way to program my subject line to ALWAYS have [secure] as the first text in subject line? even for replies and forwarded emails?
ksw

Answer (score 2):

1. In the `Quick Steps` section of the `Home` ribbon, choose the `Create New` option.
2. In the window this brings up, click on the `Choose an Action` drop down, then choose `New Message` (you will need to repeat this as needed for Replies/Forwards/etc).
3. Click on the `Show Options` flyout button.
4. In the `Subject:` text field, add your desired text (make sure to leave the `<subject>` intact for Replies/Forwards as this is the placeholder for the original message's subject).
5. Optionally choose a shortcut key and add tooltip for helpful reminders, then click `Finish`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the `ItemSend` event to clean up the subject line and prefix "[secure] " at the point in time when you press the <kbd>Send</kbd> button.

Use the [instructions here](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/macro-to-warn-before-sending-a-message-with-a-blank-subject/) to install a macro, but instead of using the code they supply, try this instead:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    strSubject = Item.Subject

    ' Remove previous [secure] and [insecure]
    strSubject = Replace(strSubject, "[secure] ", "")
    strSubject = Replace(strSubject, "[insecure] ", "")

    ' Prefix subject with [secure]
    strSubject = "[secure] " & strSubject

    ' Set the message subject
    Item.Subject = strSubject

End Sub
```

When you press <kbd>Send</kbd>, this macro will be invoked, which will strip out all existing instances of "[secure] " or "[insecure] " before prefixing the subject line with "[secure] ".

The reason for this is to avoid ending up with subject lines that have multiple tags in them due to replies and forwards. In other words, avoid:

```
[secure] Fwd: [insecure] Re: [insecure] Don't forget your TPS report
```

and have this instead:

```
[secure] Fwd: Re: Don't forget your TPS report
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create a blank email with the word or phrase you want in the subject line and then  save it as Outlook Template file , with a shortcut on a fast launch bar ?

Works a charm for me and I have different templates shortcuted that way  .

Comment: How would the OP use that method to insert their word into replies and forwarded messages?